# DevExpress: Add custom Bar to Form

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have a Problem with a custom DevExpress Bar.
I'm developing a custom Bar for DevExpress Forms and want to add this to my XtraForm.

Usually you can add new Bars through the BarManager. But there you can only add new DevExpress-Bars.

Is there a way to add my custom bar through the BarManager?

If not I want to add my bar to the toolbox in VS and add this as Component to my form. But the DevExpress Bars are hidden in the toolbox and my custom one is hidden too.
I have already tried to add the `ToolboxItem`-Attribute and the `DXToolboxItem`-Attribute to my bar:

`[ToolboxItem(true)]
 [DXToolboxItem(DXToolboxItemKind.Regular)]
 public class CustomBar : Bar
 {
    [...]
 }`

But even with this Attribute the `CustomBar` is not visible in my Toolbox.

Is there any way to make it visible?

I am using:

- C# 4.0
- DevExpress 14.2

**[UPDATE]**
To make the `CustomBar` visible in the toolbox in VS I have to add the `DesignTimeVisible`-Attribute to the bar:

`[ToolboxItem(true)]
 [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
 [DXToolboxItem(DXToolboxItemKind.Regular)]
 public class CustomBar : Bar
 {
    [...]
 }`

But is there a way to add the Bar to the BarManager **in the designer**?

Comment: You should give [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw694kde(v=vs.90).aspx) a good read. There it explains how to create custom controls and how to make it available in the toolbox.

Comment: @Oceans: Thank you for that link. I didn't set the `DesignTimeVisible`-Attribute. After adding this attribute my CustomBar is visible in the toolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to place the solution in a proper answer format for future references.

---

- **Making a custom control available in the toolbox.**

> If your components are defined by a project in the currently open
> solution, they will automatically appear in the Toolbox, with no
> action required by you. You can also manually populate the Toolbox
> with your custom components by using the Choose Toolbox Items Dialog
> Box (Visual Studio), but the Toolbox takes account of items in your
> solution's build outputs with all the following characteristics:
>
> - Implements IComponent;
> - Does not have ToolboxItemAttribute set to false;
> - Does not have DesignTimeVisibleAttribute set to false.

Source: [Walkthrough: Automatically Populating the Toolbox with Custom Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw694kde(v=vs.90).aspx)

---

- **Making a custom control show up in the designer.**

Design-time attributes are essential for displaying your control and its members correctly at design time, as they provide valuable information to a visual design tool.

Because this is a rather long list, I'll refer you to the msdn library: [Design-Time Attributes for Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx)